# Verilog assigment and replication , What do the parenthesis do?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to understand the following Verilog code sample, so far I could say that **if** `address == 0` then perform the bit-wise `&` with `data_in` **or** if it is 1 perform bit-wise `&` with `data_dir`. The thing here is that I am not sure if those parenthesis imply conditional and why it is using replication by 1 to convert vector to integer if this is the case. Thanks in advance.

```
  ....
module DE1_SoC_QSYS_i2c_sda (
                              // inputs:
                               address,
                               chipselect,
                               clk,
                               reset_n,
                               write_n,
                               writedata,

                              // outputs:
                               bidir_port,
                               readdata
                            )
;

  inout            bidir_port;
  output  [ 31: 0] readdata;
  input   [  1: 0] address;
  input            chipselect;
  input            clk;
  input            reset_n;
  input            write_n;
  input   [ 31: 0] writedata;

  wire             bidir_port;
  wire             clk_en;
  reg              data_dir;
  wire             data_in;
  reg              data_out;
  wire             read_mux_out;
  reg     [ 31: 0] readdata;
  assign clk_en = 1;
  //s1, which is an e_avalon_slave
  assign read_mux_out = ({1 {(address == 0)}} & data_in) |
    ({1 {(address == 1)}} & data_dir);

  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
    begin
      if (reset_n == 0)
          readdata <= 0;
      else if (clk_en)
          readdata <= {32'b0 | read_mux_out};
    end


  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
    begin
      if (reset_n == 0)
          data_out <= 0;
      else if (chipselect && ~write_n && (address == 0))
          data_out <= writedata;
    end


  assign bidir_port = data_dir ? data_out : 1'bZ;
  assign data_in = bidir_port;
  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
    begin
      if (reset_n == 0)
          data_dir <= 0;
      else if (chipselect && ~write_n && (address == 1))
          data_dir <= writedata;
    end



endmodule
  ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, wow, that is an ugly bit of code.

Basically it does the following:

```
assign read_mux_out = (address == 0) ? data_in : ((address == 1) ? data_dir : 0);
```

Hopefully that is a bit clearer. It is nothing more than a couple of nested multiplexers.

When the `address` is 0, `read_mux_out` will be equal to `data_in`. 
If `address` is 1, `read_mux_out` will be equal to `data_dir`. 
Otherwise `read_mux_out` will be 0.

However it is probably cleaner still to redefine `read_mux_out` as a `reg` type, and use a simple `case` statement:

```
always @ * begin
    case (address)
        2'd0:   read_mux_out = data_in;
        2'd1:   read_mux_out = data_mux;
        default: read_mux_out = 0;
    endcase
end
```

---

As a side not the only reason I can see for using the replication in that example is that it is probably code generated from some IP core generator which needs to be generalised. If you generate the data width as a multi-bit bus, the replication number would be changed to match the data width.

However I really don't know why they have done things at such a low level when using a simple and clear to read ternary operator would work equally well.

Comment: Your line of code it what I would have written for a simple mux, and your side note sounds plausible.  The only gotcha I see is that in the original code, address has a width of 2 bits.  The original code will set read_mux_out to 0 if address is set to 3 or 4.  Not sure if that's the intent since the original code is such a mess.

Comment: @BPete Hmm, that is interesting, didn't see that. Can be easily rectified, though becomes a tad more ugly.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter You were right, it was and IP core from altera to handle I2C communication to TV decoder. So if I understood IP core code is not coded by a person but an IP code generator, right?. It's quite weird, I placed  the same question in stack exchange first but having not enough replies and a -1 with a very poor explanation I tried this exchange which really helped me to move forward.

Answer (score 3):

`{1 {(address == 0)}}` is unusually because there is no replication. It could easily be written as `(address == 0)` and have the same result. A more readable form would be:

```
assign read_mux_out = (address == 0) ? data_in : (address == 1) ? data_dir : 1'b0;
```

My guesses why it was written this way:

- At some point in time (or anticipating in the future) `data_in` and `data_dir` were (or may become) multi-bit vectors. In which case it is used for making scaling easier. *But if I were to write it this way for future proofing, I'd use a parameter*
- The author maintaining a coding style. I cannot see the rest of the code, but perhaps there are places where the replicator makes sense

The only rational reason I can think of why the author use bitwise operations (`&`,`|`) indeed of conditional operators (`?:`) is if the target synthesizer poorly optimized conditional operators (I've seen this even in some modern high-end synthesizers) and it is a critical data path. There are defiantly cleaner ways of writing the code.

Comment: Your insight was really helpful, the goal here was to understand what the code was supposed to do. I will update the question with the entire code and please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @luffyKun , the code looks very odd to me mainly because `writedata` and `readdata`are 32-bits wide but only the bit 0 has any meaningful value (other bits are ignored or assigned to 0). The coding style looks old based on the non-ANSI header, each always block assigns only one reg variable, and a hint of a preference to use bitwise operators and assign statements over other approaches. I would not be surprised if it is the produce of generated code (IP, reverse-synthesis, language conversion, etc).